# Using Soap in magento

Tags: soap, magento

I'm trying to follow the information about how to use soap in magento, but always get same message in error.log

If any one experience something similar, that could give me some tip, it will be welcome.

> "PHP Fatal error:  SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://www.site.com/index.php/api/?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "http://www.site.com/index.php/api/?wsdl"\n in /var/www/test.php on line 1"

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://www.site.com/api/?wsdl');

$session = $client->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');

$result = $client->call($session, 'somestuff.method');
$result = $client->call($session, 'somestuff.method', 'arg1');
$result = $client->call($session, 'somestuff.method', array('arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3'));
$result = $client->multiCall($session, array(
    array('somestuff.method'),
    array('somestuff.method', 'arg1'),
    array('somestuff.method', array('arg1', 'arg2'))
));


// If you don't need the session anymore
$client->endSession($session);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where you have `www.site.com` in your SOAP code, replace it with `localhost` or whatever the correct URL is for your server.  You'll also need to replace `somestuff.method` with real objects and methods as per the [Magento documentation](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/api)

Comment: Thanks for your help.
But I continue having same message "Error de HTTP 500 (Internal Server Error)".

Even when I simplify the code to:
`$client = new SoapClient("http://localhost/index.php/api/?wsdl");`

Comment: have you turned on logging?  what entries are in your apache error logs, your magento system.log and exception.log?

Comment: Yes, and changing to diferents configurations I get always in error.log from apache:
`

Comment: [Tue Jul 06 11:35:18 2011] [error] [client 11.11.111.158] PHP Fatal error:  SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://www.mysite.com/index.php/api/?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "http://www.mysite.com/index.php/api/?wsdl"\n in /var/www/test.php on line 2`

Comment: `
[Tue Jul 06 11:35:18 2011] [error] [client 11.11.111.158] PHP Fatal and `error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://www.mysite.com/index.php/api/?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "http://www.mysite.com/index.php/api/?wsdl"\n in /var/www/test.php:4\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/test.php(4): SoapClient->SoapClient('http://www.mysite..')\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/test.php on line 2'

In magento nothing are writen in system and exception logs.
Its seems that I repeating always same error, but can't located yet...

Comment: For everyone that have similar problem I found clear information about: http://www.yireo.com/tutorials/magento/magento-programming/629-connecting-to-magento-with-soap-part-1

Comment: ok, after pass a while trying with SOAP, and didn't get any results, I try to use Pear XML_RPC and I get some result, well at least I get sessions Id created. And I let here also an example that connect magento to get one particular customer info:

Comment: `code <?php
require_once 'XML/RPC.php' ;
$mage_user = 'userapi';
$mage_api_key = 'userapikey';
$client = new XML_RPC_Client( '/api/xmlrpc', 'www.site.com', 80 );
$arguments = array(
    new XML_RPC_Value( $mage_user, 'string' ),
    new XML_RPC_Value( $mage_api_key, 'string' ),
);

$message = new XML_RPC_Message( 'login', $arguments );
//$client->setDebug(1); # shows debug information
$response = $client->send( $message );
$session_id = XML_RPC_decode( $response->value() );
var_dump($session_id); code`

Comment: `code $arguments = array(
new XML_RPC_Value( $session_id, 'string' ),
new XML_RPC_Value('customer.info', 'string' )
);


$filters = array( new XML_RPC_Value( array('customer_id' => new XML_RPC_Value('101543', 'string')), 'struct' ), 'array');
// create the params

$params = array(
new XML_RPC_Value($session_id, 'string'), new XML_RPC_Value('customer.list', 'string'), new XML_RPC_Value($filters, 'array')
);
//create the call
$msg = new XML_RPC_Message('call', $params);
//send the PEAR XML-RPC call
$resp =$client->send($msg);
$results =XML_RPC_decode($resp->value());
var_dump($results);
?> code`